# Creating a global object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm new to Angular and could use some help.

I'd like to maintain an object throughout my application. I created a factory that reads in a JSON file using an http.get request:

```
grey.factory('JiraData', function( $http ) {
   return {
      getData: function( callback ) {
         $http.get( 'js/testdata.json' ).success( callback );
      }
   };
});
```

I then access this data in my Controller:

```
grey.controller ( 'StoreFilterController', function( $scope, JiraData ) {
   JiraData.async().then( function( d ) {
      $scope.data = d.data;
   });
});
```

I can now access this data in the view that references my StoreFilterController. This data needs to be used and manipulated throughout my application in various controllers, factories and directives. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use cookies or localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the data to be alive after a refresh/redirect, you can use a service property, $rootScope or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) to keep the data (or a global object, like window, but try to avoid it if possible).

However, if you need your data to remain after a refresh, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Answer (score 0):

I'm new as well, but I will give this a shot ;)

in your .factory

return the object, for example:
    var o = { data:[] };
    return o;

then in your controller inject it as a dependency and then set equal to a scope variable:
    .controller('Ctrl', ['data',
    function(data){
        $scope.item = data.data[];
    }]);

Is this close?